# how to make this type bubble navigation ?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I was wondering how would i go about making the bubble navigation menu like seen here on the right side of this website. 
http://www.ru4children.org/#home

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i think im being straight forward for what im asing. @kmsdev

Comment: Stack Overflow is about solving problems in **your** code. Not writing it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using fullpage.js plugin: http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/